# ESRI silverlight print map without using print task

Tags: silverlight, printing, maps, esri

I have a silverlight application which different panels, One of the panel contains the ESRI map, I want to print what is coming on the map panel, It's more like a print screen for map (but it should not include rest of the controls of the client application).

On investigation I found that we can use PrintTask but it uses GP server. I do not want to invoke the ESRI service for print.

Is there any other way to print what is coming on the screen (inside the map panel) in the silver light?

Atul Sureka

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) - from the "Remarks" on that page "For bitmap printing, you can print the entire Silverlight control by setting the PrintPageEventArgs.PageVisual property to the layout root of the Silverlight content. Alternatively, you can print a portion of the Silverlight control by setting PrintPageEventArgs.PageVisual that contains the items you want to print to the named UIElement that you want to print."

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version of the Esri Silverlight API, you have access to client side printing. See their example here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#ClientPrinting

It is nice in that it gives you a proper WYSIWYG interface for printing, visibly seeing the extent and can handle custom markers way better than the print service. The downside is though that unless your source map is high enough resolution you'll end up with quite low-res maps unless you perform some kind of map switching when a user triggers the print interface. You'll also need to define print templates in xaml rather than in ArcMap.

It basically boils down to cloning your map and copying all the layers across.