# Save controls content/screenshot (without using third party library) to the file

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a silverlight application in which I have a map control.  I want to save the map into a jpg/png file format to the disk.

I got this link http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-a-Silverlight-Screen.aspx but it uses some third party library to save the WriteableBitmap into the file/disk. I do not want to use any third party control. Is there any standard .Net API/way to save the image capture to the disk?

Atul Sureka

Comment: possible duplicate of [ESRI silverlight print map without using print task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902162/esri-silverlight-print-map-without-using-print-task)

Comment: no it is not the duplicate one.